# How do I get the red "invalid" outline style to show on an Angular custom control

Tags: angular

I made a stackblitz perfectly describing my problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mlo6y6

How do I get the custom control to do the same thing as the standard control and show the red outline after it has been made dirty but has no input?

Comment: Consider moving components in their own folders to make it more readable - apart from that I assume you're following https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control ?

Comment: Please ensure your question is self contained (i.e. doesn't depend on external links) and includes a [MRE].

Comment: @MikeS. Yea of course, but that's doesn't solve my issue, or rather, googles issue, since their own example doesn't even get the red outline.

For this example it's not really neccessary to be so particular about the folder stucture.

Comment: @DaleK Yea, I'm aware but I was really hoping it could be easily embedded here and "Run code" would work but I don't see how to do it.

I'm sure people MUCH prefer having the stackblitz rather than having me copy and paste each and every individual file's code directly into the question - which would be a mess without a lot of work to make it one script. I did this because I want to work directly off Googles exact example of a custom control to make it clear what I mean.